# Are there any interactive decompilers besides HexRays?

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompilation, decompiler

Are there any decompilers that generate pseudo-code that is interactive? By interactive, I mean you can select a variable and rename it. Or you can select a function call and rename the function. Or you can select an instruction in the disassembly and it will take you to the equivalent line in the pseudo-code.

I know that the HexRays plugin for IDA Pro can do this but are there any alternatives that also have this interactive functionality?

I am looking for an interactive decompiler (meaning the output should be C-like pseudocode) - not an interactive disassembler.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No, there is no other interactive decompiler, at least not for native codes.

Long answer: The Hex-Rays decompiler was created with the idea of interactiveness while all the other decompilers for native code that I know (I'm not talking about Java or .NET) were created as batch tools. The closest to a half interactive decompiler is [Snowman](https://derevenets.com/), but is not really interactive (unless selecting which function you want to decompile when using the IDA Plugin is considered interactiveness.)

There is a toy "decompiler" (if the name is appropriate, as it's more a translator to pseudo-C than anything else) in Hopper but is neither interactive.

Boomerang, REC, and all the other abandoned decompiler projects that I know, were created either as command line batch tools or had a GUI just to let you select a binary.

So, as said at the beginning: the only interactive decompiler for native codes is the Hex-Rays one.

PS: I don't know why people is not focusing in the question instead of proposing their favourite tools... A disassembler is not an interactive decompiler.

Answer (score 1):

The plasma project seems to have an interactive decompiler: https://github.com/joelpx/plasma

From the documentation:

```
$ plasma -i tests/server.bin
>> v main # or v 0xFFFFFF (replace 0xFFFFFF with the address of the function)
# You are now in visual mode. Press P to define the function. Then press TAB to decompile the function into pseudocode.
# You can hover over a variable using your arrows keys and press R to rename a variable. You can press X to see all xrefs to the variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Radare2](https://github.com/radare/radare2) seems to meet your requirements. It's a command line program, there's no GUI available (but there is a visual mode). It takes a bit of getting used to, I'd recommend the [radare2 book](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/) to start out.

Comment: You can use the Bokken frontend for radare if a UI is a must: http://www.bokken.re/index.html

Comment: @Necrolis I thought I remembered there being a GUI for radare2, but I didn't see it in a Google search. Thanks! In general though, the CLI will be more powerful of course.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting alternative to IDA is [Medusa](https://github.com/wisk/medusa), its not fully complete, but may server your needs.

However, its sounds as though you are actually after the decompiler side of things, more than just a labeled CFG, in which case you might want to look at [snowman](https://github.com/yegord/snowman). [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com/#start) has a plugin that wraps snowman that might do what you need. You can also try [REC](http://www.backerstreet.com/rec/recdload.htm), though I have never fiddled with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting decompilers from this list: http://www.capstone-engine.org/showcase.html

Answer (score 0):

I have been there, I have made the quest.
Use [vivisect](https://github.com/vivisect/vivisect) . Contribute to it! I do have binary ninja (signed up for a beta tester) and I have to say: It is nowhere near as functional as vivisect.
Binja only has a better graph layout and few more extras on the IL side. That's all.
Vivisect had the goal of becoming IDA replacement. And is damn close. However a lot of work is still to be done.